# MSSQL update set from output clause

Tags: sql-server

**Context**
I got a temporary table which is filled/adjusted by users. Let's call the table `tmp`, with columns `ID`, `updated_at`, `price`, `foreign_ID`. Every time the user enters a new price, the `price` column is filled and the `updated_at` and `ID` are created automatically. `foreign_ID` is `NULL` until the record is processed to another table, when my `foreign_ID` should contain the ID of the other table.

Periodically I update a table with prices, let's call it `prices`. Here are all prices stored from different sources, among them from the `tmp` table. The `prices` table has the columns `ID`, `updated_at`, `price`.

**question**
I want to insert the data from my `tmp` table into `prices` table, and update the column `foreign_ID` with the corresponding `ID` from my `prices` table. How can I insert new rows in a table and update/set a IDs in another table?

My desired result after the periodic update is a new entry in the `prices` table with the new prices which were not yet processed, and a `foreign_ID` in my `tmp` table which corresponds with the `ID` in my `prices` table.

I know I can output the inserted IDs using the following query:

```
insert into prices
output inserted.ID
select price
from tmp;
```

I'm struggling to see how I can use the `inserted.ID` to update my `tmp.foreign_ID` column with the output above.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also `INSERT` the values from the `OUTPUT` clause into another table as well, so if you need those you can still reference them.

Without proper sample data and behaviour, this is just an example but should, hopefully, set you on the right path as it shows you how to get the values from `inserted` into another object. You can then use that object to do the additional task(s) you need:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            SomeString varchar(10));
GO


DECLARE @IDs table (ID int);

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeString)
OUTPUT inserted.ID
INTO @IDs (ID)
VALUES('asdjgkde'),('sdflhdglf');

SELECT *
FROM @IDs;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly declaring a table and then using `update tmp set foreign_ID = fID from @ID foreign_ID is NULL;`